# How can I run shopify dev app from localhost in a test store?

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost, shopify, shopify-app

I have a Shopify app running on live server. Now, I want to setup it's development environment on localhost.

So, my question is, Is it possible to run a Shopify development app from localhost to a test store?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Services like https://ngrok.com/ can make the process easier if your app receives webhooks or carrier service rate requests from Shopify.